# Update excel spreadsheet from another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, excel, com-server

I've created COM server using C# where my clients can receive real time updates.
Updates usually fired from different threads.
But I've noted that Excel crashes when callback methods updates spreadsheet.
Is there any way to call updates in UI thread?

P.S. I know about RTD feature of Excel. But it doesn't suit my needs because i need several parameters in one update.

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is the Invoke / BeginInvoke Method of ISyncronizedInvoke

on your UI thread, take an arbitrary control and keep that reference ...

from the thread that wants to fire an update, call Invoke or BeginInvoke on that control (Control implements ISyncronizedInvoke) with a delegate that you want to execute on the UI thread ... from that delegate you may call your COM server

//EDIT: example code

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Thread someWorkerThread;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExApp;
        Worksheet wrkSheet;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ExApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            ExApp.Visible = true; // or else we won't see the window

            var books = ExApp.Workbooks;
            var wrkBook = books.Add();
            var sheets = wrkBook.Worksheets;
            wrkSheet = sheets.get_Item(1);

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheets);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wrkBook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(books);

            someWorkerThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(threadHandler));
            someWorkerThread.Start(this);
        }

        private void threadHandler(object obj)
        {// this will be executed on a seperate worker thread
            Control mainFrm = obj as Control;
            if (mainFrm == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Need to have a Control as parameter");
            for (int i = 1; i < 50;i++ )
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2500);
                mainFrm.Invoke(new Action<int>(doStuff), i); // this will invoke the main UI thread
            }
        }

        private void doStuff(int i)
        {// this will be executed on the main UI thread
            var range = wrkSheet.Range[string.Format("A{0}", i)];
            range.Value = "Hello World!";
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range);
        }


        #region designer stuff
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(76, 84);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(149, 13);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.label1.Text = "I am an ordinary windows form";
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**be advised: this example does not clean up the wrkSheet reference and the ExApp reference ... you have to release them before you exit your application**

Comment: sorry didn't get how can I reach instance of ISyncronizedInvoke?

Comment: do you mean to create hidden form?

Comment: no ... you have your program ... i guess your program has a user visible form ... your calling thread will need a reference to that form and use it to invoke to the UI thread .... need an example?

Comment: ah... it's MS Excel - I'm not sure there is ISyncronizedInvoke implemented

Comment: see example code ... be advised: this example does not clean up the wrkSheet reference and the ExApp reference ... you have to release them before you exit your application